# NSDictionary length :unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, xml, parsing

Hi guys I'm trying to parse some XML data to my tableview and get this failure: unrecognized selector sent to instance. I have an XMLReader class which is used for converting XML to NSDictionary which i have from this site:
http://ios.biomsoft.com/2011/09/11/simple-xml-to-nsdictionary-converter/
how can I get app work?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yxz"];
//get content of url
NSURLRequest* request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse*response;
NSError *error;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error);
}

// NSLog(@"data: = %@",data);
NSString* dataAsString =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//NSLog(@"dataAsString= %@",dataAsString);
//parse content
feeds = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSDictionary *xmlDictionary = [XMLReader dictionaryForXMLString:dataAsString error:&error];
if(xmlDictionary==nil){NSLog(@"ERROR: Dictionary is NULL");}
else{
    if ([xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"OrderList"]==nil) {NSLog(@"OrderList not found");}
        else{
            if([[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"OrderList"]objectForKey:@"Order"]==nil) {NSLog(@"No Orders");}
            else
            {
                feeds = [[xmlDictionary objectForKey:@"OrderList"]objectForKey:@"Order"];
            }

        }
    }
NSLog(@"XMLDictionary: %@",xmlDictionary);
}
```

The XML example(deleted the values which are not important anyway)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<OrderList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xyz/schema/OrderListSchema.xsd">
  <Order>
    <ID></ID>
    <Name></Name>
    <Payment></Payment>
    <Marge></Marge>
    <CountryISO2></CountryISO2>
    <Status ></Status>
  </Order>

2014-04-09 16:42:16.786 djisjdk[714:60b] -[__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized 
selector sent to instance 0x8c46d10
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x287a, 0x015718b9 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 
'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.3
frame #0: 0x015718b9 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
```

Comment: Give full exception message and stack trace - which line is it from?

Comment: did you mean that? i added it under the code

Comment: That doesn't tell me which line. I know that you are using a dictionary when the code expects a string, but you need to know where - which dictionary - before you can fix it...

Comment: I made a breakpoint in All Exceptions and it stops in the main file at this line:
@autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }

Comment: I dont know, the only dictionaries I have are XMLDictionary which is above (NSDictionary) and another NSMutableDictionary called order.

Comment: btw thanks for your response @Wain

Comment: Which is the last log you see before the app crashes?

Comment: Print the instance '0x8c46d10' by typing 'po 0x8c46d10' when the breakpoint activates. Simply the error means that there is no method 'length' belongs to that instance. Then, post it here what you've got.

Comment: Pressing continue (a couple of times) when it hits that breakpoint should give you a stack trace. Step through your code rather than trying to wait for the exception

Comment: i wrote po 0x8... and get this:
{
    text = "\n  \n    16344863";
}

Comment: @Wain thanks to your comments i could find the problem. 
I wanted to ask you that how you knew that my code expected a string when i was using a Dictionary.
the problem was in my XML which had a fotmat which my converter couldn't use.

Comment: I have some space characters in the XML and my converter cant handle the space characters-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> -[__NSDictionaryI length]: unrecognized 
>   selector sent to instance

This message tells you that `NSDictionary` (or, specifically, the private immutable subclass `__NSDictionaryI`) received a call to the `length` method, which it doesn't respond to.

'length' is a common method to call on a string, so it's a fairly safe bet that that is what the code which threw the exception was expecting. `NSData` also has a `length` method, but this seems less likely based on your code.

You need to step through the code to find where you have a dictionary but the code expects a string (or data).